# Retina display images for Google Maps in PhoneGap app

Tags: google-maps, cordova

Is there a way to get retina display images to show up when using Google Maps within a PhoneGap iOS app? If I use my map on an iPhone 3, markers show up with the normal/low res icon. If I use the map on an iPhone 4, markers use the same low res icons instead of what I would expect to be higher resolution icons. I tried adding optimized: true to my marker but that made no difference.

Comment: I met the same problem on my android device. Though I found that google map's StaticMap(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values) has the parameter scale getting a higher resolution, no similar is found for javascript API v3.